# How to get value from controller to directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a question about angular's directives. 
How can i get value from controller function, which is calling by ng-click in my directive ?

This is my html code:

```
<tbody data-ng-repeat="car in $data">
    <tr>
        <th><a href="#/detail" ng-click="onShowCarDetails(car)">{{car.Registration}} </a></th>

    </tr>
</tbody>
```

controller function:

```
module.controller("searchController", [$scope, function($scope){
    $scope.onShowCarDetails = function (car) {
         $scope.car = car;
}
```

and directive:

```
directive("searchDirective", [function () {

return {
    restrict: 'AEC',
    scope: {
        onShowCarDetails: '&',
    },
    controller: ["$scope", function ($scope) {
        $scope.onShowCarDetails({car: CAR})
    }],
}
```

Is that possible to have in CAR(directive) information from $scope.car from searchController? 
Or may I call function onShowCarDetails(car) in diractive to get value directly from html ? If so, then how to do this?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$emit` and `$on` to send and retrieve data to the parent scope.

**controller :**

```
function Controller($scope){

    $scope.data = [
        {
            Registration: 'blabla'
        },
        {
            Registration: 'blop'
        }
    ];

    $scope.onShowCarDetails = function (car) {
        //Emit an event
        $scope.$emit('send', car);
    }


}

angular
.module('app.controller', [])
.controller('Ctrl', Controller);
```

**directive :**

```
function searchDirective() {

    function link(scope, elm, attr, ctrl){

        //Listen for event 
        scope.$on('send', function(e, value){
            //Retrieve car value from Controller
            console.log(value);
        });

    }



    var directive = {
        restrict: 'AE',
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        controller: 'Ctrl',
        link: link
    };

    return directive;

}

angular
    .module('app.directive', [])
    .directive('searchDirective', searchDirective);
```

**template.html :**

```
  <h1>Template</h1>


<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="car in data">
    <td><a href="#/detail" ng-click="onShowCarDetails(car)">{{car.Registration}}</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then, you can call your directive by calling `<search-directive></search-directive>`.

Now, when `onShowCarDetails` is fired, you'll able to retrieve the data from your directive.

Comment: I used $rootscope, but your answer is very usefull. Thanks a lot for help :)